# How to use a Named Range/Array to AutoFilter a Table?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I am using the below code to set an array to the values in a Named Range (containing account numbers) and then use that array as the criteria to AutoFilter a table (Table1).

```
Sub FilterRangeCriteria()

Dim vCrit As Variant
Dim rngCrit As Range

Set rngCrit = wsL.Range("CritList")

vCrit = rngCrit.Value
wsO.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=8, _
    Criteria1:=vCrit, _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

I can see that the array contains all of the values from the named range however the table that I'm trying to filter will eliminate all rows below the header and not show any rows with the criteria from the named range.

[image: Table that needs to be filtered.]

[image: Named Range in column.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if `CritList` is a single column or row.  Otherwise, you'll have to create a 1D array from the values.

```
Sub FilterRangeCriteria()

    Dim vCrit As Variant
    Dim rngCrit As Range

    Set rngCrit = wsL.Range("CritList")

    vCrit = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Unique(rngCrit))
    wsO.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
        Field:=8, _
        Criteria1:=vCrit, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

### EDIT

For the filter to work properly, the numeric values need to be converted to strings.

```
Sub FilterRangeCriteria()

    Dim vCrit As Variant
    Dim rngCrit As Range

    Set rngCrit = wsL.Range("CritList")

    vCrit = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Unique(rngCrit))
    
    Rem Numeric filter values need to be converted to strings
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(vCrit) To UBound(vCrit)
        vCrit(n) = CStr(vCrit(n))
    Next
    
    wsO.Range("A11").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The CritList is a single column of account numbers.  I have tried updating the code with the change in vCrit and have also updated Field:=1 but it results in the same thing as before.

Comment: Also, why did you change Field:=8 to Field:=1?  When I look at the table after I run this code it changed the filtered column to the first column but that column doesn't contain the account numbers.  I'm new to VBA so I assume I'm misunderstanding how this works.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I created a test table with 1 column.   Transposing the values should work.  Try changing the variable assignment in your original code to : `vCrit = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngCrit)`

Comment: Hi @TinMan It is still not showing the filtered results in the table.  I've added a picture to my original post above with the table and the named range that I'm using as my array in case that helps.

Comment: If you send me the workbook at tinmanse@aol.com, Ill take a look at it.

Comment: Hello @TinMan I have just emailed you the file.  Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help with this question!

Answer (score 1):

### Filter Excel Table Column on Values of a Named Range

```vb
Sub FilterRangeCriteria()
    
    ' Source - read criteria list
    ' 'wsL' is the code name of a worksheet containing this code
    Const sRangeName As String = "CritList"
    
    ' Destination - filter a table
    ' 'wsO' is the code name of a worksheet containing this code
    Const dtblName As String = "Table1"
    Const dlcName As String = "Ledger Account"
    
    ' Keep in mind that this would fail on 'UBound(cData, 1)'
    ' if there was only one cell in the named range.
    Dim cData As Variant: cData = wsL.Range(sRangeName).Value
    
    ' "AutoFilter" 'likes' strings and the array needs to be 1D,
    ' hence write the values from the 2D one-based one-column criteria array,
    ' converted to strings, to a 1D one-based string array ('sArr').
    
    Dim sArr() As String: ReDim sArr(1 To UBound(cData, 1))
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(cData, 1)
        sArr(r) = CStr(cData(r, 1))
    Next r
    
    ' Reference the destination table.
    Dim dtbl As ListObject: Set dtbl = wsO.ListObjects(dtblName)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Remove any filters.
    If dtbl.ShowAutoFilter Then
        If dtbl.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then dtbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Else
        dtbl.ShowAutoFilter = True
    End If

    ' Reference the destination table criteria column.
    Dim dlc As ListColumn: Set dlc = dtbl.ListColumns(dlcName)
    
    ' Apply the filter.
    dtbl.Range.AutoFilter dlc.Index, sArr, xlFilterValues

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Table filtered.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: I am really new to VBA but this does work!  I'll have to study this and learn how this works!  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Everyone has there own method of approaching a solution and this is solution has sparked a couple of questions in my quest for learning.

Comment: Everyone has there own method of approaching a solution and this is solution has sparked a couple of questions in my quest for learning.  1) Why are you using Constants for the table, column to be filtered and CritList?  2) Why do you remove any existing filters first before filtering again?  I assume in your experience you have found this method of writing code helpful and I'd like to understand.

Comment: 1.) I'm using constants to make the code flexible i.e. if you have the same requirement for another named range, table, and column, you can change the values in one place and don't have to read through the code to replace the values. A more advanced way would be to convert these constants to arguments of the sub, e.g. `Sub FilterRangeCriteria(ByVal sWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal sRangeName as String, ByVal dWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal dtblName As String, ByVal dlcName As String)`.

Comment: Then you could call this sub in another sub with `FilterRangeCriteria wsL, "CritList", wsC, "Table1", "Ledger Account"` after removing the constants and replacing `wsC` and `wsL` with `sWorksheet` and `dWorksheet` respectively in the code. It may sound scary, but you could try it on your own. 2.) If you don't remove the filters, you might be filtering an already filtered worksheet and get fewer resulting rows. Try it by filtering one column with a simple code. Then with the same code filter another column and see for yourself that the previous filter is not removed automatically.